# resource style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout not found after updating to API 28

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Today I updated my project from API 27 to API 28. Before the update I was not getting any error. I am getting the below error while building the gradle after changing the compileSdkVersion and buildVersion. I am using Kotlin as my primary programming language for the project. This is the error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  Output:  /Users/sagarsuri/Downloads/MyProject/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeReleaseResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:2778: error: resource style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout (aka com.sagar.myproject:style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout) not found.
  /Users/sagarsuri/Downloads/MyProject/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeReleaseResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:4480: error: resource style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout (aka com.sagar.myproject:style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout) not found.
  error: failed linking references.
```

This is my app module `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sagar.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 11
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
}

ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = '28.0.0'
    glideLibraryVersion = '4.6.1'
    retrofitLibraryVersion = '2.4.0'
    rxJavaVersion = '2.1.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"

    //Glide library
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideLibraryVersion"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glideLibraryVersion"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    //Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofitLibraryVersion"

    //RxJava
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxJavaVersion"

    //ObjectBox
    implementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-android:$objectboxVersion"
    implementation "io.objectbox:objectbox-kotlin:$objectboxVersion"
    kapt "io.objectbox:objectbox-processor:$objectboxVersion"

    //MaterialDialog
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'

    //ReactiveNetwork
    implementation 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork-rx2:0.12.3'

    //MultiDex
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //Fotoapparat
    implementation 'io.fotoapparat.fotoapparat:library:2.2.0'

    //ChartView
    implementation 'com.github.razerdp:AnimatedPieView:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.leinardi.android:speed-dial:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'me.shaohui.advancedluban:library:1.3.5'
    implementation 'com.github.antonKozyriatskyi:CircularProgressIndicator:1.0.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Please let me the know what is causing the error. The version of Android Studio is `3.2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52642377/android-studio-resource-linking-failed)? It helped me. I have multimodule project. You need to replace

> style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout

with

> @style/Widget.Support.CoordinatorLayout

In all your styles.xml files. This issue happened with me when I tried to migrate on AndroidX (not only updated to API 28)