# Android Studio resource linking failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-coordinatorlayout

I tried to update my app to sdk version 28 and I am constantly getting this error:

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\nick\AndroidStudioProjects\BrowserElement\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2641: error: resource style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout (aka de.test.browserelement:style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout) not found.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\nick\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\cbd40259f1851f4cf906e8ce48516057\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\nick\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\Users\nick\AndroidStudioProjects\BrowserElement\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\Users\nick\AndroidStudioProjects\BrowserElement\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\Users\nick\AndroidStudioProjects\BrowserElement\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\Users\nick\AndroidStudioProjects\BrowserElement\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        de.test.browserelement\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\Users\nick\AndroidStudioProjects\BrowserElement\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
    Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

I tried rebuilding the app, updating the build tools and implementating the CoordinatorLayout separately.I don't really know why it is giving me this error, it worked for SDK version 27.

Did I do something wrong with my build.gradle file?:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
 compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "de.test.browserelement"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

And for the CoordinatorLayout I am using, here is the .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> error: resource style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout (aka de.test.browserelement:`style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout`) **not found**.

Go to your `values.xml` and change this:

```
style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout
```

To:

```
@style/Widget.Support.CoordinatorLayout
```

For example:

```
<item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Support.CoordinatorLayout</item>
```